# USB Created with dd will not boot

Tags: rhel, bootable

I downloaded the newest RHEL 8 ISO (9 GB) and created a bootable USB with a `dd` command in CentOS 7.9. But it would not boot at system startup. I tried it with 2 different USBs but to no avail.

Secondly I tried the `Rufus` software on Windows. It said that there is some kind of *"Lock"* on the ISO image from the creators, so it, (Rufus), also used the `dd` option to create the USB. The result is the same; it will not boot to start the installation process.

`dd if=rhel-8.4-x86_64-dvd of=/dev/sdd1` command was used.

Comment: Is it USB3? I remeber some general problem with USB3 bootable devices on the motherboard level.

Comment: What `dd` command did you use? Have you run checksum on USB and image? Which RHEL version (8.0 ... 8.4)? Which architecture?   Do you get any message at all on boot? Do you have another PC you can try to boot from?

Comment: `dd if=rhel-8.4-x86_64-dvd of=/dev/sdd1` command was used.
I didn't run checksum on USB and image.
Its RHEL 8.4.0, arch is x86_64.
There is no message. It just skips the USB drive as if its not even there.
And yeah I tried on another PC. Same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `of=/dev/sdd` not `sdd1`. Would think Rufus did so, but worth a shot. I am not familiar with the options Rufus gives.

Note: it will erase entire USB. The used command:

```
dd if=rhel-8.4-x86_64-dvd of=/dev/sdd1
```

writes to partition 1, not the disk itself.

It is also recommended using something like:

```
dd bs=4M if=path/to/rhel-8.4-x86_64-dvd of=/dev/sdX conv=fsync oflag=direct
```

where `/dev/sdX` is replaced with for example `/dev/sdd`. Do a `sync` for good measure and make sure it is unmounted properly (ejected) before it is removed.

One can also do:

```
cat path/to/rhel-8.4-x86_64-dvd.iso > /dev/sdX
```

You can also checksum the ISO by:

```
sha256sum rhel-8.4-x86_64-dvd.iso
```

Checksum for (`10130292736` byte) 8.4 Binary ISO `rhel-8.4-x86_64-dvd.iso` is:

```
48f955712454c32718dcde858dea5aca574376a1d7a4b0ed6908ac0b85597811
```

- [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.4 for x86_64](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/479/ver=/rhel---8/8.4/x86_64/product-software)
- Same for [this image](https://developers.redhat.com/products/rhel/download) `8.4.0   2021-05-18  DVD iso 9GB`

---

To verify the USB one can for example use:

```
head -c $(stat -c '%s' dvd.iso) /dev/sdX | sha256sum
```

to get sha-sum, or:

```
cmp -n "$(stat -c '%s' dvd.iso)" dvd.iso /dev/sdX
```

to do a byte comparison. It does not report anything if equal.

Comment: /dev/sdd solved the problem. Just as precaution I did the checksum but all was okay.

Comment: @TaimurFalak Yes. The ISO is a so called hybrid ISO using ISO Linux and El Torito. To see the MBR for example: `head -c 512 dvd.iso | xxd`. ISO 9660 reserves the first 32 KB as system area for arbitrary purposes. It has MBR, GPT, EFI boot etc. When you boot your machine read the start of the disk. If it does not have a valid boot area it does not know what to do with it and ignores it. When you write to  `sdX1` you do not write this information to an area where your machine looks for it at boot.

Answer (score 1):

of=/dev/sdd**1**

Herein should lie the problem.

When writing a bootable linux iso to USB drive, use not the partition device filename, but the disk device filename which wont have a number appended.

Comment: thtas exactly what I did. ibuprofen suggested other steps also to be sure but as soon as I used `sdd` instead of `sdd1`, it solved the problem. Still I have to start the system, press `Esc` key, go to option menu, select USB Drive then it started the installation process.